# nodejs "this" is undefined in transforming

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is my transform code

i do not know why this is undefined in post transform to use showCategories

```
 const Transform = require('../.././transform');

module.exports = class postTransform extends Transform {

    transform(item) {
      
        return {
           
            'id' : item._id ,
            'title' : item.title,
             
            ...this.showCategories(item)  //here is the error
          
        }
    }
     
    showCategories(item) {
        const categoryTransform = require('./categoryTransform');
        
        if(this.withCategoriesStatus) {
            return {
                categories : new categoryTransform().transformCollection(item.categories)
            }
        }
        return {}
    }
    
    withCategories() {
        this.withCategoriesStatus = true;
        return this;
    }

    
    
}
```

and here is  my route

```
////some code
const HomePostController = require(`${ControllerApi}/v1/postController`);

    homePostRouter.get('/posts' , HomePostController.index.bind(HomePostController));
////some code
```

and my post controller code

```
module.exports = new class postController extends Controller {
    index(req , res) {
        const page = req.query.page || 1
        this.model.Post.paginate({} , { page , limit : 21 , populate : ['categories']})
        .then(result => {
            if(result) {
                return res.json({
                    data : new postTransform().withPaginate().transformCollection(result),
                    success : true ,
                    status : 200
                });
            }
    
            res.json({
                message : 'Posts empty',
                success : false ,
                status : 404 
                
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

i want to show the relative categories and tags when calling all posts i use ref in post model to the category and tag model

Comment: Please edit into the body of your post: How does `this is undefined in post transform to use showCategories` manifest? (Quote error messages!) Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You new'ed up your class, and there's no constructor. You did not call transform function nor do I see a `withPaginate()` definition. Is that in a separate file?

I think reading through this will help with using Classes in JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes . If you still need help after reading through this, I will attempt to pull in your example and work through it with you.